# Show 'free shipping' button in Magento product grid

Tags: php, html, magento

I want to make a button in the product grid for products that have free shipping enabled, like this method: http://www.immense.net/magento-free-shipping-certain-products/

To make it clear: I want a button in the product grid, above the "Add to cart" button, for the products with free shipping enabled. I already done the steps from the URL and tried to put the code in the product grid, but that doesn't work.

Do you know how I can do this?

Thank you!

Edit 2:
Fabian and others,

It works great now, thank you! But I want also that when the product price is above 65, the "Free shipping" message is also displayed. OR the product must have the free shipping attribute to YES, OR the product must be 65 euro or more expensive to show the "Free shipping" text.

I edited the code like this, but only the products with "Free Shipping" on YES are displayed well. The products above 65 not. Can you see what I've done wrong?

Thanks!

```
<?php
 // Determine if product "free shipping" is true
if ($_product->getGratisVerzending())
{
echo '<span class="freeShip">'.$_product->getAttributeText('gratis_verzending').'</span>';
}

 // Determine if product costs more than 65
else if ($_product->getPrice() > 65)
{
echo '<span class="freeShip">'.$_product->getAttributeText('gratis_verzending').'</span>';
}
?>
```

Comment: there is an error thrown. go in the backend `System > Config > Developer > Logging Settings` and activate logging, but more important, activate the developer mode http://tiagomatos.org/blog/?tag=mage_is_developer_mode then you should see the error - did you change the attribute_code of free_shipping_discount? Magento is not interessted in the translation ;-) only in the code.

Comment: and @sonassi wrote a very nice entry about debugging magento http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: Okay, logging is already enabled, so I will take a look on that. Sure I edited the attribute_code. ;) Will also take a look on your URLs!

Comment: check what is in getPrice() and we are talking about integers, remove the ' and the else {} is unecessery too.

Comment: Fabian, how can I check what's in getPrice()? The new code above still doesn't work. Googled a lot yesterday, but can't find anything that resolves this problem.

Comment: var_dump($_product->getPrice())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Reindex.
2. You should check wether the attribute_code is:  free_shipping_discount
3. and wether the "used in product listing" attribute option is YES
4. Then check, wether you spelled it correctly `getFreeShippingDiscount` and if this doesn't work, check wether the information is their.

   ```
   <?php Mage::log($_product->getData()); ?>
   ```

   This is an array and will be logged (enable logging!). Check wether the attribute is listed. If it is not, then the attribute is not loaded with the collection, normally because of 2.

Comment: Fabian, thank you for your response! Will look at it tomorrow!

Comment: Fabian, I just edited the startpost. Can you take a look on that? Thanks again!

Comment: Fabian, it works now, thank you! But I have another question. Can you please check my startpost?

Comment: The output is correct. The output is for example 65.0000, that looks correct to me. Also tried to change to getPrice() > 65 to 65.0000 but that also doesn't work. The output of debugging of ($_product->getPrice() > 65) is 1. Maybe we have to say, if output is 1, place the text?

Comment: 65.0000 is not greater then 65.

Comment: What is the problem? The price is not greater than 65, so nothing is shown. If you want to show your notice, change the if statement >=65 or raise the price.

Comment: No but when the price is 70 or 100 for example, the notice is also not shown. That's the problem. ;)

Comment: Did you check with an echo befor and after the if and try a var_dump on everything in the if(), is this true? It sounds like a small problem.

Comment: Fabian, I did it! It's just so simple. But that's as usual when you find the answer! ;) When "free shipping" is disabled for a product, the "free shipping" is empty. That's the whole problem! I have removed the attribute text for the 65+ products, and filled it with the correct text. Thanks again for helping!